# FluentValidation passes an empty string with NotEmpty() when i set an int to empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have this validation code

```
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("[[[Name is required.]]]");
        const string sortWeightError = "[[[Sort weight must be a value between 1 and 10000.]]]";
        RuleFor(x => x.SortWeight).NotEmpty().WithMessage(sortWeightError);
```

where Name is a `string` and SortWeight is an `int`.
When I validate with SortWeight set to 0 and the name to empty string then both fail like they should.

But as soon as i also clear the SortWeight to an empty string (was 0 before) then Name (yes Name, not SortWeight) passes validation even tho it's still an empty string.

If I set the SortWeight to int? instead of int it all works as intended except that it then allows 0 which i fix with GreaterThan.

But still, very odd behaviour, documentation said it should make sure it's not null or empty/whitespace string no matter which type. And weirdest of all, it still did fail the SortWeight field when i passed in an empty string, but it then passed another field (Name) that should always have failed because that always had an empty string.

Comment: Just tried updating fluentvalidation in nuget, still no go.

Comment: Something is not clear - you say "SortWeight to an empty string" when it is an int or int?, but that is not possible in C#. Maybe you can post a full code block which fails unexpectedly?

Comment: I meant empty field in the browser.